# Receiving error 'Use of undeclared identifier' when running a target that I added as a test app in order to use resources from the main app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I have a main app, a huge one. 
I need to test some complex things so I added a target to the project which is in fact a tabbed bar template. 
If I run this target I receive an app with a different app delegate and it runs like a different app.
Now I am trying to add to this target some classes from the main app in order to start testing them (they are mainly objective-c).
The problem is that I add the .m file to the target and the error 'Use of undeclared identifier' is shown. It's like the .m file cannot see its own .h file.
I tried adding the path to the header search path of the target with no success.

Thanks

Comment: share a small sample. this sounds too obscure for a reliable answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a .pch that imported Foundation to all my main project. So my files on the main project didn't see the Foundation because I had to add a .pch for the new target.
The same applies to the -Swift.h file. I had to add the main app -Swift.h file to the new target.